# Resources for writing kernel in C

Tags: c, kernel, osdev

I don't want to write my own boot loader -- happy to use Grub.

I just want to implement pre-emptive multi threading, a basic file system, and virtual memory.

I want something that can run on top of qemu.

What's a good resource (book / tutorial) for accomplishing this goal?

Thanks!

Comment: osdev.org might be of interest.

Comment: duplicate of [How can I build a small operating system on an old desktop computer?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1224617).  And see also [How to make the kernel for my bootloader?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33603842) for a Hello World 32-bit-mode C kernel for an x86 PC booting in legacy BIOS mode.

Answer (score 9):

The [tutorials at osdev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Tutorials) should get you started. They even have a page for [getting started](http://wiki.osdev.org/Getting_Started). Writing an OS is not for the faint of heart. Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

You may also refer to the labs on [MIT 6.828](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/), the support code can be checked out by *git clone http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/jos.git*, and it's easier for you to implement your own kernel from here.

Answer (score 1):

i think the best way would be to just pickup any of the toy micro-os projects (see freshmeat.net) and look how it's done